# Is there a better way to do that in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have this function to read a file and convert it to a list of two-elements lists:

```
(def f1 "/usr/example")

(defn read-file [file]
  (let [f
        (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
          (doall (map list (line-seq rdr))))]
    (cond 
      (= file f1) (map #(map read-string (split (first %) #" ")) f)
      :else (map #(map read-string (split (first %) #"\t")) f))))
```

I use `cond` to `split` the file correctly(I have two types of files, the first separates elements by spaces and the second, with tabs).

The first type of file would be like:

```
"1.3880896237218878E9 0.4758112837388654
1.3889631620596328E9 0.491845185928218"
```

while the second is:

```
'1.3880896237218878E9\t0.4758112837388654
1.3889631620596328E9\t0.491845185928218"
```

I get the result I want, for example:

```
((1.3880896237218878E9 0.4758112837388654) (1.3889631620596328E9 0.491845185928218))
```

But I wonder if there's a cleaner way to do that, maybe using less `map` functions or doing it without `cond`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns a vector of vectors, splitting individual lines on arbitrary whitespace and using `Double/parseDouble` to read in the individual doubles. What it doesn't handle are any single or double quote characters in the files; if they are part of the actual input, I suppose I'd just preprocess it with a regex to get rid of them (see below).

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io] '[clojure.string :as string])

(defn read-file [f]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader f)]
    (mapv (fn [line]
            (mapv #(Double/parseDouble %) (string/split line #"\s+")))
          (line-seq rdr))))
```

As for the aforementioned preprocessing, you could use `#(string/replace % #"['\"]" "")` to remove all single quotes. That would be appropriate if they occur at the beginning and end of the input, or perhaps the individual lines. (If the individual numbers are quoted, then you need to make sure you're not removing all delimiters between them -- in such a case it may be better to replace with a single space and then use `string/trim` to remove any whitespace from the ends of the string.)

Comment: Thanks! That was great! The quotes I added here by mistake, there are only numbers in the file.